# How to refer to a line or table row I've just inserted

Tags: vba, ms-word

I feel I must be missing something obvious. I'm using VBA to build a Word document by writing lines to it one at a time. Once I've written a line, I need to format it - this could be bolding, setting tabstops, etc. But in order to format a line, I have to be able to refer to it. All the formatting facilities operate on a Range or a Selection - how do I identify the line I've just inserted as the Range I want to operate on? (Also, same question for table rows, as the doc also includes tables I'm building one row at a time, and I need to format cells as I go).

Comment: Maybe if you showed your code someone might suggest a modification?

Comment: Sounds like you're coming at this problem backwards. ***Start*** with the `Range` (zero length), and then set the `Range.Text` to the line you want to write.  Now you have a `Range` containing the text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to insert text and format it as you go, using a `Range` object. It's better to *not* try to simulate how a user works by using `Selection` and `TypeText`. The code runs more slowly and it's more difficult to work precisely. There can be only one Selection, but code can work with many Ranges...

The other important point to remember is to declare and instantiate objects as they're created - tables and table rows, for example.

```
Dim rng1 as Word.Range, rng2 as Word.Range
Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Content
rng1.Text = "line one" & vbCr
rng1.Font.Bold = True
rng1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rng1.Text = "line two" & vbCr
rng1.Font.Bold = False
rng1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
Set rng2 = rng1.Duplicate
rng2.Text = "line three" & vbCr
rng2.Font.Italic = True
'You can still work with the first range
rng1.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
'
Dim tbl as Word.Table, rw1 as Word.Row, rw2 as Word.Row
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add
Set rw1 = tbl.Rows(1)
Set r2 = tbl.Rows.Add
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a much easier approach.

Answer (score -3):

```
Sub FormatBold()
Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String
StartWord = "STARTSTART"
EndWord = "ENDEND"

With ActiveDocument.Content.Duplicate
    .Find.Execute Findtext:=StartWord & "*" & EndWord, MatchWildcards:=True
    .MoveStart wdCharacter, Len(StartWord)
    .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -Len(EndWord)
    .Font.Bold = True ' Or whatever you want to do
End With

End Sub
```

Format the text while you write it:

```
Sub StartTyping()

Selection.TypeText Text:="This is the "
Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
Selection.TypeText Text:="sentence"
Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
Selection.TypeText Text:=" I am inserting." & vbCr

End Sub
```

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, the way to specify the Range for the line is to search the document for the text string that I've just inserted? But the same text string could occur many times in the doc - how do I pick up the one I've just inserted, and not the earlier ones?

Comment: You could search for a significant startString "Start_27012019_string" and a significant endString "end_27012019_string" prior to inserting your text. If they are not there you are save.

Comment: Can I phrase the question in another way? It seems to me that inserting a line to a doc and then wanting to format it is a very common requirement, so I imagined it would be easy - I assumed there was some obvious method that I was just unaware of. Having to use a complicated search to identify the line I've just inserted seems crazily complex for such an apparently simple task. Or am I just approaching this whole task the wrong way? Is there a bettter way to create a document line by line and format it?

Comment: I'have updated my answer. Is this a useful alternative?

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the TypeText method a try.